# Why do we allow 3D questions again?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

3D questions are piling up. It is no longer believable by askers that 3d questions are not our thing. We have too many of them. The fact is that we are not really equipped to handle them at this time, but if it persists we will defacto become also a 3D StackExhange want it or not.

We need to decide if we want to tolerate them. They are much more technical in nature, which usually makes them much harder to answer.

Also where do we draw the line? Is asking help for scripting 3D apps appropriate? What about file format internals, shader design, export issues, etc.? When do we push questions out to GameDev or Blender, do we include CAD apps, because these are intertwined with 3D? What about 3D printing?

Do we want 3D to be a first class citizen? Why not? If we do then we need to address the rules.

If not we should consider kicking them out. Or they will become first class citizen eventually.

Comment: I don't exactly what your statement "nobody believes anymore that you politely suggest for them to move to better pastures (for their benefit)" means. Would you mind trying to rephrase that part?

Comment: @ZachSaucier you can nolonger say we dont deal in 3d becsue the user will just point to all the 3d answers and questions. Thus this has no merit. Also even if the questions have no answers now they will have answers. Pretty soon its too late to recant the position. Its fine if you want 3d included but not if you do not what the can of worms here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry I see a total of 295 questions with `3d` related tags.

And just look at the wealth of answers : 
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d 
(that was sarcasm)

I don't think we support 3D here. Most of the question have 1 answer or none at all. If I were a 3D creator, this is definitely *not* the place I'd ask just looking at the existing questions and their traffic. Your arguments *for* the 3D questions really only make sense if there were *actual answers* to the questions.

Having *questions* without *answers* really only reflects poorly on the site. I personally think it would be better to not have this black hole of unanswered questions.

I've always felt, like video, 3D is a very *specialized* area of design and not used by the bulk of "Graphic" designers. Sure it *can* be used, but there's a difference between can and is.

**I think the bulk of the issue is where do we send them?** Blender.se is, well, for Blender. Where else would be appropriate? (as a non-Blender.SE users, I'd think expanding Blender.SE to *all* 3D would not only help that beta site but solve this issue for a few other SE sites).

Perhaps they should simply be closed without referring to anywhere specifically.

Comment: I am not actually for 3d. I just wish that we take stance on the issue. Because it reflects badly. Its not like that traffic is needed. Eventually this needs to be adessed.

Comment: Can we push to place them in http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ ? Seems this stack is more appropriate because of the heavy-technical side of the questions I've looked through.

Comment: I see highly technical 3D questions too. Aren't there already a lot of 3D forums elsewhere? Software-specific, even? Can we just point them there?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scott, it's not great for the site to have these unanswered questions. Some of them probably bring in views as well, which is annoying for the people looking for the answer.

But, there are many sides to ambiguous 3D definition. It can mean so many things, and of all those things, I think one fits here well.

We do know how to create visual 3D effects - making 2D objects *look* 3D. So in that respect, it's on topic.

However, as you've mentioned, we're not a fountain of knowledge when it comes to the technical side. Nor do we have many users that regularly use 3D Modelling/CAD software.

If we had one resident expert and a few intermediate 3D users who're enthusiastic about helping people with 3D issues, we could maybe make it a little bit successful. I think that's sort of what we've been hoping for, that some expert will see all these unanswered Qs and go to work providing answers - but it doesn't look like it's going to happen.

I think the mathematical questions look particularly out of place here.

---

> Maybe we should make technical 3D questions and how-to's for 3D modelling software off topic?
>
> > - Then specify that questions about creating visual 3D effects on graphics are on topic?

Comment: I dont like to answer the 3d questions because they are usually super annoying.  I did that for 15 years and for most part i have nothing to add to the subject. I only answer when im on a foul mood.

Answer (score -1):

If somebody asks how to create a '3D' image or effect in a 2D vector design package or Photoshop, they should probably be directed politely towards the Blender site. I say that because if a designer has never tried 'real' 3D work, there is the risk they will make a few web searches and conclude (from all the sponsored hits) that they have to spend thousands on Maya, SolidWorks etc... then give up on the idea. But since Blender is free and runs on any platform they can 'have a go' at work or at home, create real 3D models, and hopefully realise they need to use the right tool for the job.

(CSx and Blender user for 8 years)

Comment: The problem is blender.se since you dont acceopt maya questions we get maya questions. So why should we promote blender specifically?

Comment: Please don't copy and paste answers for multiple questions